# Extension methods and lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, spreadsheetlight

I am using the spreadsheetlight library to access  excel files.

How can I shorten the following construct through extension methods and lambda expressions ? I want to count all cells with boolean values.

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, SLCell>> cells = sl.GetCells();

int nCount = 0;

foreach (Dictionary<int, SLCell> Value in cells.Values)
{
    foreach (SLCell Cell in Value.Values)
    {
        if (Cell.DataType == CellValues.Boolean)
        {
            nCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ for this:

```
int ncount = cells.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Values)
                         .Count(x => x.DataType == CellValues.Boolean);
```

By `SelectMany(x => x.Values)` we create another `IEnumerable` that enumerates over all `SLCell Cell`s.

Then the `Count(x => x.DataType == CellValues.Boolean)` counts the number of cells where the `.DataType` is `CellValues.Boolean`.